# Python, pandas: Removing values with a small length in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all values in this pandas dataframe that have that have less than length 3, but not to all columns

```
import pandas 

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],'player': ['w', 'George', 'Roland'], 'hometown': ['Miami', 'Caracas', 'Mexico City'], 'current_city': ['New York', '-', 'New York']})

columns_to_add = ['player', 'hometown', 'current_city']

for column_name in columns_to_add:
    df.loc[(len(df[column_name]) < 3), column_name] = None
```

I am trying the following code but I get the following error:

```
KeyError("cannot use a single bool to index into setitem")
```

Note:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[df[columns_to_add].apply(lambda col: col.str.len() < 3)] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id  player     hometown current_city
0   1     NaN        Miami     New York
1   2  George      Caracas          NaN
2   3  Roland  Mexico City     New York
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `applymap` to calculate the length, then `np.where` to update:

```
df[columns_to_add] = np.where(df[columns_to_add].applymap(len) >=3, 
                              df[columns_to_add], None)
```

Output:

```
   id  player     hometown current_city
0   1    None        Miami     New York
1   2  George      Caracas         None
2   3  Roland  Mexico City     New York
```

Comment: How can I manage a NoneType value in my dataset? TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: use `lambda x: x if x is None else len(x)` instead of just `len`. Note, in any case you should run that line once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'replace' function in DataFrame :

```
def find_string_less_lenth(list_of_values):
    return [i for i in list_of_values if len(i)<3]
for column_name in columns_to_add:
    df[column_name] = \
df[column_name].replace(find_string_less_lenth(df[column_name].values), 'none')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution might be

```
new_df = df[columns_to_add]
new_df[new_df.applymap(len) > 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the issue that took in consideration all variables correctly was the following:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],'player': ['w', 'George', 'Roland'], 'hometown': ['Miami', 'Caracas', 'Mexico City'], 'current_city': ['New York', '-', 'New York']})

columns_to_add = ['player', 'hometown', 'current_city']


df0[df0[columns_to_add].apply(lambda col: col.str.len() < 3)] = np.nan
df = df0.where(pandas.notnull(df0), None)
```

One important thing to understand is that columns_to_add does not include all the columns in the dataframe